# How to pass JSON object from Controller to view

Tags: php, jquery, json, parsing

There are many threads on the subject, but I cannot find any that use PHP. I want to pass the json object to the view, where I will later update an element with the returned json object.
Here is my code:
View:

```
<input type="submit" class="button" name="insert" value="load"/>

<script>   
jQuery(document).ready(function() {  
    var $ = jQuery;    
    var baseUrl = [location.protocol, '//', location.host, location.pathname].join('');
    $('.button').click(function(){ 
        var clickBtnValue = $(this).val();
        var ajaxurl = baseUrl+"?action=load";   
        data =  {'action': clickBtnValue};  
        $.post(ajaxurl, {}, function (result) {
            alert(result);
        });  
    });

});
 </script>
```

And Controller is:

```
<?php
set_include_path(get_include_path().':../');    
require_once('_inc/common.php');   
$action = req('action');

if ($action == 'load') {
    $result = parse_ini_file('test.ini');   
    $json = json_encode($result);
}
```

[UPDATE]
After the code to the answers provided, I now get an Json.parse error. So I edited my code again but the error still persists, I checked online to see if my Json is a valid json and no error on the validator.

```
 $result = parse_ini_file($config_file);
$json = json_encode(array($result),JSON_HEX_QUOT); 
var_dump($json);
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

View

```
var request = $.ajax({

                          url: ajaxurl,
                          method: "POST",
                          data: {},
                          dataType: "json"
                      }); 
        request.done(function( msg ) {console.log("d");});       
        request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {console.log( "Request failed: " + textStatus );});

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Like said above, you aren't outputting the JSON, and also you are not setting the content type. But I noticed something else, you did not assign the return type of the post request (JSON).

```
$.post(url, {}, function (data) {
     alert(data);
}, 'JSON');
```

Be also sure that you encode an array and not a false value, parse_ini_file returns false when it fails.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But now, I  get a Json.parse error.: Unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    <script>   
jQuery(document).ready(function() {  
    var $ = jQuery;    
    var baseUrl = [location.protocol, '//', location.host, location.pathname].join('');
    $('.button').click(function(){ 
        var clickBtnValue = $(this).val();
        var ajaxurl = baseUrl+"?action=load";   
        data =  {'action': clickBtnValue};  
        $.post(ajaxurl, {}, function (result) {
            var json =JSON.parse(result);
            console.log(json); //see in browser console
        });  
    });

});
 </script>
```

And Controller is:

```
<?php
set_include_path(get_include_path().':../');    
require_once('_inc/common.php');   
$action = req('action');

if ($action == 'load') {
    $result = parse_ini_file('test.ini');   
    echo json_encode($result);
}
```